# Mock tool for REST server json data

Tags: web-apps, rest, mocks

I need a mock tool to return json data, mocking my REST API 's return data.
[Mocknoon](https://mockoon.com/) can do the job BUT there is no easy way to share mock code/data between team members or maybe it has but I didn't find it. Now I have export json file, others then can import it.

Not only do I need to share  that between frontend developers but also between frontend and backend REST developer. So I am looking for a tool that can export the mock codes then I can git check in

Comment: And you cannot mock inside code directly? In unit tests?

Comment: There are many reasons why mocking inside code is just a "quick and dirty" solution.